# Testing Angular Service gives error: No module: ngResource

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I have yeoman-angular set up with the following app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource','ui.bootstrap'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      ...
  }]);
```

and a service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('UserSvc', [function() {
        return {
            name : '',
            topicOrder: 'lec_type',
        };
    }]);
```

and the following test:

```
describe('Service: UserSvc', function () {

  beforeEach(module('mfApp'));

  var UserSvc;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_UserSvc_) {
    UserSvc = _UserSvc_;
  }));

  it('should do something', function () {
    expect(UserSvc.topicOrder).toEqual('lec_type');
  });

});
```

I've tried my best to inject $resource in the test (although the srvice itself isn't denpend on ngResource), but when I run the test, I get this error

```
Error: No module: ngResource
```

if I remove the dependencies from the module itself,

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

then the tests run successfully

I've really tried everything but failed

Answer (score 45, accepted):

in your testacular.conf.js / karma.conf.js did you include angular-resource.js; e.g.

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/vendor/angular/angular.js',
  'app/vendor/angular/angular-*.js',
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent hours on this, but I'm new to AngularJS. I guess I need to do some more reading. Also, there's not much documentation on testing and working with Karma/Testacular. Can recommend some resources on testing. Thanks

Comment: This was the same problem I encountered. Be sure that after including your new component in testacular.conf.js / karma.conf.js that you remember to restart your Testacular/Karma session

Comment: Great help. My setup's path looks something like this, FYI:       `app/bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js`.

Comment: omg. Thanks digger! I recently upgraded to Angular1.2rc, bootstrap3 and overhauled my yo/grunt/bower bins. Then my tests would throw weird errors... There were a million places I was thinking to look but not this one. Saved me a ton of time!

Comment: damnit, it took me hours to get to this page. "yeoman angular karma error module dependency" and the likes yielded tons of results, but none with just this information.

Answer (score 3):

After including your new component, remember to **restart** your Testacular/Karma session.