# AngularJs Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am new in angular JS
I want test angular-seed sample, e2e test run ok, but i can not test unit test (directive, ...), i get this sample from github, and not change this, but have this problem

i get this error in firebug : ReferenceError: module is not defined

i seen this link but not resolve my problem

[Testing Angular Service gives error: No module: ngResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657846/testing-angular-service-gives-error-no-module-ngresource)

please help, thanks

Comment: Showing some code of a test suite would be helpful. the error is very generic.

Comment: this sample in github not run unit test https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Answer (score 0):

Publish your code snippet. That might help me getting the issue.
Anyway, you can instantiate your module in beforeEach method,

beforeEach(function(){module("myApp"); // myApp is your module});

This should be defined before injecting controller. Hope, this might help